# Python 3.5 vs. 3.6 what made "map" slower compared to comprehensions

Tags: python, performance, python-3.5, python-3.6, cpython

I sometimes used `map` if there was a function/method that was written in C to get a bit extra performance. However I recently revisited some of my benchmarks and noticed that the relative performance (compared to a similar list comprehension) drastically changed between Python 3.5 and 3.6.

That's not the actual code but just a minimal sample that illustrates the difference:

```
import random

lst = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(100000)]
assert list(map((5).__lt__, lst)) == [5 < i for i in lst]
%timeit list(map((5).__lt__, lst))
%timeit [5 < i for i in lst]
```

I realize that it's not a good idea to use `(5).__lt__` but I couldn't come up with a useful example right now.

The timings on Python-3.5 were in favor of the `map` approach:

```
15.1 ms ± 5.64 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
16.7 ms ± 35.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

While the Python-3.6 timings actually show that the comprehension is faster:

```
17.9 ms ± 755 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
14.3 ms ± 128 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

My question is what happened in this case that made the list-comprehension faster and the `map` solution slower? I realize the difference isn't that much, it just made me curious because that was one of the "tricks" I sometimes (actually seldom) used in performance critical codes.

Comment: Hm, maybe it depends on the function? for example, `str` seems to still be faster with `map`, so `timeit.timeit("list(map(str, range(100000)))", number=1000)` gave me `18.98376033702516` and `timeit.timeit("[str(i) for i in range(100000)]", number=1000)` gave me `24.40201253897976`

Comment: That pattern holds for `int` and `float` ... and that pretty much exhausts my use-cases for `list(map(...))` over list-comprehensions ;)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I can confirm your observations. However I can also see a decline in performance with `map` and increase in performance for the comprehension for other methods, e.g. `a = [' {}'.format(i) for i in range(100000)]` while timing `list(map(str.strip, a))` vs. `[i.strip() for i in a]` (although `map` is still faster there)

Comment: @poke I thought it was the "fairest" comparison possible because the `COMPARE_OP` bytecode is the fastest way from within Python code to call the `__lt__` method which is what `map` (in this case) also calls. Both ways actually avoid (most of) the function call overhead this way.

Comment: Possible candidates for the `map` slowdown include a change to `map.__next__` that doesn't pay off when the mapped function is `(5).__lt__`. ([3.5 version](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1168), [3.6 version](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1186)) The difference is small enough that finding the true cause and *verifying* that that's the cause could be difficult.

Comment: I have added additional tests to my answer that, I believe, show that evaluation of `f = (5).__lt__` is slower in Python 3.6 compared to Python 3.5.

Comment: @user2357112 You cannot infer that “map got slower” from this test. You can say that “this particular test got slower compared to this particular list comprehension” which can be caused by a large number of reasons though, one being that `map` got slower but equally likely is that list comprehensions in general got faster. Since both do very different things, you cannot attribute the difference to just `map`. – In fact my own tests show that in general the execution time got faster (at least for me), and OP’s list comprehension just got a lot faster compared to other comprehensions.

Comment: @poke: I'm not asserting that `map` itself must have gotten slower. Language is ambiguous; my reference to "the `map` slowdown" was not intended to claim that `map` itself is the culprit, just like if I was talking about "my computer slowing down", I wouldn't be claiming that my physical hardware must be responsible. (The snippet using `map` did run slower in absolute terms in MSeifert's Python 3.6 timings, so an explanation only in terms of list comprehension improvements wouldn't be satisfying.)

Answer (score 5):

I think a fair comparison involves using the same function and same testing conditions in Python 3.5 and 3.6 as well as when comparing `map` to list comprehension in a chosen Python version.

In my initial answer I have performed multiple tests that showed that `map` was still faster by a factor of about two in both versions of Python when compared to list comprehension. However some results were not conclusive and so I performed some more tests.

First let me cite some of your points stated in the question:

> *"... [I] noticed that the relative performance [of `map`] (compared to a similar list comprehension) **drastically** changed between Python 3.5 and 3.6"*

You also ask:

> *"My question is what happened in this case that made the list-comprehension faster and the map solution slower?"*

It is not very clear if you mean that map is slower than list comprehension in Python 3.6 or if you mean that map is slower in Python 3.6 than in 3.5 and list comprehension's performance has increased (albeit not necessarily to the level of beating `map`).

Based on more extensive tests that I have performed after my first answer to this question, I think I have an idea of what is going on.

However, first let's create conditions for "fair" comparisons. For this we need to:

1. Compare performance of `map` in different Python versions using the same function;
2. Compare performance of `map` to list comprehension in the same version using same function;
3. Run the tests on same data;
4. Minimize contribution from timing functions.

Here is version information about my system:

```
Python 3.5.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Mar  6 2017, 12:15:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
IPython 5.3.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
```

and

```
Python 3.6.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul 20 2017, 13:14:59) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
IPython 6.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
```

Let's first address the issue of "same data". Unfortunately because you effectively are using `seed(None)`, each data set `lst` is different on each of the two versions of Python. This probably contributes to the difference in performance seen on two Python versions. One fix would be to set, e.g., `random.seed(0)` (or something like that). I chose to create the list once and save it using `numpy.save()` and then load it in each version. This is especially important because I chose to modify your tests slightly (number of "loops" and "repeats") and I have increased the length of your dataset to 100,000,000:

```
import numpy as np
import random
lst = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(100000000)]
np.save('lst', lst, allow_pickle=False)
```

Second, let's use `timeit` module instead of IPython's magic command `%timeit`. The reason for doing this comes from the following test performed in Python 3.5:

```
In [11]: f = (5).__lt__
In [12]: %timeit -n1 -r20 [f(i) for i in lst]
1 loop, best of 20: 9.01 s per loop
```

Compare this to the result of `timeit` in same version of Python:

```
>>> t = timeit.repeat('[f(i) for i in lst]', setup="f = (5).__lt__;
... import numpy; lst = numpy.load('lst.npy').tolist()", repeat=20, 
... number=1); print(min(t), max(t), np.mean(t), np.std(t))
7.442819457995938 7.703615028003696 7.5105415405 0.0550515642854
```

For unknown to me reasons, IPython's magic `%timeit` is adding some time compared to `timeit` package. Therefore, I will use `timeit` exclusively in my testing.

NOTE: In the discussions that follows I will use only minimum timing (`min(t)`).

### Tests in Python 3.5.3:

#### Group 1: map and list comprehension tests

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import timeit

>>> t = timeit.repeat('list(map(f, lst))', setup="f = (5).__lt__; import numpy; lst = numpy.load('lst.npy').tolist()", repeat=20, number=1); print(min(t), max(t), np.mean(t), np.std(t))
4.666553302988177 4.811194089008495 4.72791638025 0.041115884397

>>> t = timeit.repeat('[f(i) for i in lst]', setup="f = (5).__lt__; import numpy; lst = numpy.load('lst.npy').tolist()", repeat=20, number=1); print(min(t), max(t), np.mean(t), np.std(t))
7.442819457995938 7.703615028003696 7.5105415405 0.0550515642854

>>> t = timeit.repeat('[5 < i for i in lst]', setup="import numpy; lst = numpy.load('lst.npy').tolist()", repeat=20, number=1); print(min(t), max(t), np.mean(t), np.std(t))
4.94656751700677 5.07807950800634 5.00670203845 0.0340474956945

>>> t = timeit.repeat('list(map(abs, lst))', setup="import numpy; lst = numpy.load('lst.npy').tolist()", repeat=20, number=1); print(min(t), max(t), np.mean(t), np.std(t))
4.167273573024431 4.320013975986512 4.2408865186 0.0378852782878

>>> t = timeit.repeat('[abs(i) for i in lst]', setup="import numpy; lst = numpy.load('lst.npy').tolist()", repeat=20, number=1); print(min(t), max(t), np.mean(t), np.std(t))
5.664627838006709 5.837686392012984 5.71560354655 0.0456700607748
```

Notice how second test (list comprehension using `f(i)`) is significantly slower than third test (list comprehension using `5 < i`) indicating that `f = (5).__lt__` is not identical (or almost identical) to `5 < i` from the code perspective.

#### Group 2: "individual" function tests

```
>>> t = timeit.repeat('f(1)', setup="f = (5).__lt__", repeat=20, number=1000000); print(min(t), max(t), np.mean(t), np.std(t))
0.052280781004810706 0.05500587198184803 0.0531139718529 0.000877649561967

>>> t = timeit.repeat('5 < 1', repeat=20, number=1000000); print(min(t), max(t), np.mean(t), np.std(t))
0.030931947025237605 0.033691533986711875 0.0314959864045 0.000633274658428

>>> t = timeit.repeat('abs(1)', repeat=20, number=1000000); print(min(t), max(t), np.mean(t), np.std(t))
0.04685414198320359 0.05405496899038553 0.0483296330043 0.00162837880358
```

Notice how again first test (of `f(1)`) is significantly slower than second test (of `5 < 1`) further supporting that `f = (5).__lt__` is not identical (or almost identical) to `5 < i` from the code perspective.

### Tests in Python 3.6.2:

#### Group 1: map and list comprehension tests

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import timeit

>>> t = timeit.repeat('list(map(f, lst))', setup="f = (5).__lt__; import numpy; lst = numpy.load('lst.npy').tolist()", repeat=20, number=1); print(min(t), max(t), np.mean(t), np.std(t))
4.599696700985078 4.743880658003036 4.6631793691 0.0425774678203

>>> t = timeit.repeat('[f(i) for i in lst]', setup="f = (5).__lt__; import numpy; lst = numpy.load('lst.npy').tolist()", repeat=20, number=1); print(min(t), max(t), np.mean(t), np.std(t))
7.316072431014618 7.572676292009419 7.3837024617 0.0574811241553

>>> t = timeit.repeat('[5 < i for i in lst]', setup="import numpy; lst = numpy.load('lst.npy').tolist()", repeat=20, number=1); print(min(t), max(t), np.mean(t), np.std(t))
4.570452399988426 4.679144663008628 4.61264215875 0.0265541828693

>>> t = timeit.repeat('list(map(abs, lst))', setup="import numpy; lst = numpy.load('lst.npy').tolist()", repeat=20, number=1); print(min(t), max(t), np.mean(t), np.std(t))
2.742673939006636 2.8282236389932223 2.78504617405 0.0260357089928

>>> t = timeit.repeat('[abs(i) for i in lst]', setup="import numpy; lst = numpy.load('lst.npy').tolist()", repeat=20, number=1); print(min(t), max(t), np.mean(t), np.std(t))
6.2177103200228885 6.428813881997485 6.28722427145 0.0493010620999
```

#### Group 2: "individual" function tests

```
>>> t = timeit.repeat('f(1)', setup="f = (5).__lt__", repeat=20, number=1000000); print(min(t), max(t), np.mean(t), np.std(t))
0.051936342992121354 0.05764096099301241 0.0532974587506 0.00117079475737

>>> t = timeit.repeat('5 < 1', repeat=20, number=1000000); print(min(t), max(t), np.mean(t), np.std(t))
0.02675032999832183 0.032919151999522 0.0285137565021 0.00156522182488

>>> t = timeit.repeat('abs(1)', repeat=20, number=1000000); print(min(t), max(t), np.mean(t), np.std(t))
0.047831349016632885 0.0531779529992491 0.0482893927969 0.00112825297875
```

Notice how again first test (of `f(1)`) is significantly slower than second test (of `5 < 1`) further supporting that `f = (5).__lt__` is not identical (or almost identical) to `5 < i` from the code perspective.

### Discussion

I do not know how reliable are these timing tests and it is also difficult to separate all factors that contribute to these timing results. However we can notice from the "Group 2" of tests that the only "individual" test that significantly changed its timing is the test of `5 < 1`: it went down to 0.0268s in Python 3.6 from 0.0309s in Python 3.5. This makes the list comprehension test in Python 3.6 that uses `5 < i` to run faster than a similar test in Python 3.5. However, this does not mean that list comprehension become faster in Python 3.6.

Let's compare *relative* performance of `map` to list comprehension for the same function in the same Python version. Then we get in Python 3.5: `r(f) = 7.4428/4.6666 = 1.595`, `r(abs) = 5.665/4.167 = 1.359` and in Python 3.6: `r(f) = 7.316/4.5997 = 1.591`, `r(abs) = 6.218/2.743 = 2.267`. Based on these relative performances we can see that in Python 3.6 performance of the `map` relative to the performance of list comprehension is at least the same as in Python 3.5 for the `f = (5).__lt__` function and this ratio has even improved for a function such as `abs()` in Python 3.6.

In any case, I believe that there is no evidence that list comprehension became faster in Python 3.6 neither in the relative nor in the absolute sense. The only performance improvement is for `[5 < i for i in lst]` test but that is because `5 < i` itself became faster in Python 3.6 and not due to the list comprehension itself being faster.

Comment: You raise good points for the general case (much appreciated!). However I still don't know what's the reason that made `map` ~20% slower and the comprehension ~20% faster _in my case_. Note that the comparison was intentionally not "fair" (except for the seeding issue - I overlooked that - but it gives the same results if I use `pickle` to use the same list in both versions). It compared the "fastest" way to solve the problem with `map` with the fastest way to solve the problem with a list comprehension. :)

Comment: @MSeifert If you look at my test results, you will see that `map`'s performance has increased (from Python 3.5 to 3.6) by `100*(4.66655-4.5997)/4.5997 = 1.4%` and list comprehension's performance has increased by `100*(4.9465-4.57)/4.57=8.2%`. So, `map`'s performance is virtually unchanged (within errors) and list compr. performance had a *very modest* increase almost bringing it to the same speed as `map` (within errors). I certainly do not see a 20% decrease in `map`'s performance when tests are "enhanced" (use `timeit`, identical data arrays, increase size of data, etc.) as described above.

Comment: @user8371915 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think a fair comparison would involve using the same function. In the case of your example, when comparison is fair, `map` still wins:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version)
3.6.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul 20 2017, 13:14:59) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
>>> import random
>>> lst = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(100000)]
>>> assert list(map((5).__lt__, lst)) == [5 < i for i in lst]
>>> f = (5).__lt__
>>> %timeit list(map(f, lst))
4.63 ms ± 110 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>>> %timeit [f(i) for i in lst]
9.17 ms ± 177 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

While in Python 3.5 (at least on my system) `map` is faster than in Python 3.6, so is list comprehension:

```
>>> print(sys.version)
3.5.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Mar  6 2017, 12:15:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
>>> %timeit list(map(f, lst))
100 loops, best of 3: 4.36 ms per loop
>>> %timeit [f(i) for i in lst]
100 loops, best of 3: 8.12 ms per loop
```

Still, when using the same function, `map` is ~2x faster than list comprehension in both Python 3.5 and 3.6.

### EDIT (Response to @user2357112 comments):

It is my opinion that performing "fair" comparisons is important in answering OP's question: *"My question is what happened in this case that made the list-comprehension faster and the map solution slower?"* (last paragraph). However, in the first paragraph, @MSeifert says: *"... [I] noticed that the relative performance (**compared to a similar list comprehension**) drastically changed between Python 3.5 and 3.6"* That is, the comparison is between a `map` and `list comprehension`. Yet, @MSeifert tests are set-up as follows:

```
timig_map_35 = Timing(list(map(f, lst)))
timing_list_35 = Timing([g(i) for i in lst])
```

This kind of testing makes it difficult to find the cause of timing differences: are they because list comprehension became faster in 3.6 or map became slower in 3.6 or `f(i)` is slower in 3.6 or `g(i)` is faster in 3.6...

Therefore, I proposed to introduce `f = (5).__lt__` and use the same function in both `map` and list comprehension tests. I have also modified @MSeifert test by increasing the number of elements in the list and redusing number of "loops" in the `timeit`:

```
import random
lst = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(1000000)] # 10x more elements
f = (5).__lt__
%timeit -n1 -r1000 list(map(f, lst)) # f = (5).__lt__
%timeit -n1 -r1000 [f(i) for i in lst] # f(i) = (5).__lt__(i)
%timeit -n1 -r1000 [5 < i for i in lst] # g(i) = 5 < i
%timeit -n1 -r1000 [1 for _ in lst] # h(i) = 1
```

In Python 3.6 I get:

```
43.5 ms ± 1.79 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1000 runs, 1 loop each)
82.2 ms ± 2.39 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1000 runs, 1 loop each)
43.6 ms ± 1.64 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1000 runs, 1 loop each)
23.8 ms ± 1.27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1000 runs, 1 loop each)
```

In Python 3.5 I get:

```
1 loop, best of 1000: 43.7 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 1000: 78.9 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 1000: 46 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 1000: 26.8 ms per loop
```

In my opinion this shows that list comprehension is slightly faster in 3.6 than in 3.5 except when `f` is used. Therefore, it is difficult to conclude that it is the `map` that is slower in Python 3.6 or is first `timeit` above is slower because of the call to `f` being slower. Therefore I performed two more tests:

```
%timeit -n1 -r1000 list(map(abs, lst))
%timeit -n1 -r1000 [abs(i) for i in lst]
%timeit -n1000000 -r1000 f(1)
```

In Python 3.6 I get:

```
25.8 ms ± 1.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1000 runs, 1 loop each)
67.1 ms ± 2.07 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1000 runs, 1 loop each)
64.7 ns ± 2.22 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1000 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

In Python 3.5 I get:

```
1 loop, best of 1000: 38.3 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 1000: 56.4 ms per loop
1000000 loops, best of 1000: 59.6 ns per loop
```

This shows that `map` *can be* **significantly faster** than list comprehension for some functions: specifically, for `abs(x)` relative performance of `map` versus "list comprehension" in Python 3.6 is `67.1/25.8 = 2.60` while in Python 3.5 it is `56.4/38.3 = 1.47`. Therefore it is interesting to know why @MSeifert test shows that `map` is slower in Python 3.6. My last test above shows timing test for `f(1)` "alone". I am not sure how valid this test is (unfortunately) - I wanted to avoid using `map` or `[for]` to eliminate one variable - but it shows that in Python 3.6 `f = (5).__lt__` became slower than in Python 3.5. Therefore I conclude that it is the particular form of the function `f` (`(5).__lt__`) whose evaluation slowed and not the `map` function. I know this last "alone" test is likely a bad test, however, the fact that `map` is very fast (relatively or absolutely) when used with `abs` shows that the problem is in `f` and not in `map`.

NOTE: Python 3.5 uses IPython 5.3.0 and Python 3.6 uses IPython 6.1.0.

Comment: The question is about why the performance comparison changed between 3.5 and 3.6. Whether it's "fair" to do the comparison doesn't matter.

Comment: @user2357112 No. @MSeifert says: _"... [I] noticed that the **relative performance** (compared to a similar list comprehension) **drastically changed** between Python 3.5 and 3.6"_ My experiment shows that *when using identical functions* (=fair comparison) **relative performance** between `map` and list comprehension did not change from Python 3.5 and 3.6 (at least not **drastically**) which is what OP stating has changed.

Comment: While I agree that the difference is not drastic (and disagree with your judgment of fairness), this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @user2357112 I have added additional tests that, I believe, show that evaluation of `f = (5).__lt__` is slower in Python 3.6 compared to Python 3.5.