# How does dtype affect row and column operation speed in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, row-major-order

I'm trying to understand how to best utilize the C-ordering of numpy arrays to write high performance code.  My expectation was that operations which traverse rows should be faster than those which traverse columns.  Indeed, this was true for the first example I tried:

```
X = np.ones((10000,10000),dtype='int64')
print(X.dtype)
print(X.flags)

%timeit np.sum(X,axis=0)

%timeit np.sum(X,axis=1)
```

This produces output:

```
int64
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
10 loops, best of 3: 79.6 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 61.1 ms per loop
```

Which is what I expected, since summing along the rows should be faster than summing along the columns.

Here is where I get very confused.  If I change the dtype to float64, then column operations become almost twice as fast as row operations:

```
X = np.ones((10000,10000),dtype='float')
print(X.dtype)
print(X.flags)

%timeit np.sum(X,axis=0)

%timeit np.sum(X,axis=1)
```

Produces output:

```
float64
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
10 loops, best of 3: 67.7 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 123 ms per loop
```

Can someone please clarify why this is happening?

**EDIT**: It was suggested in the comments that I try again with a smaller matrix, (1000,1000).  When I run:

```
import time
import numpy as np

X = np.ones((1000,1000),dtype='float')
print(X.dtype)
print(X.flags)

%timeit np.sum(X,axis=0)
%timeit np.sum(X,axis=1)

X = np.ones((1000,1000),dtype='int64')
print(X.dtype)
print(X.flags)

%timeit np.sum(X,axis=0)
%timeit np.sum(X,axis=1)
```

I get output:

```
float64
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
1000 loops, best of 3: 598 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.06 ms per loop
int64
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
1000 loops, best of 3: 788 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 632 µs per loop
```

So the effect is persisting.

Comment: What are your `numpy` and `python` versions?

Comment: @DanielF Python 3.6, Numpy 1.11.3.

Comment: Try reducing the size of `X` (i.e. `(1000,1000)`) and see if the time difference jumps from ~200% to ~110% at some point.  You may be caching.

Comment: @DanielF I'm going to try this ASAP.  I upgraded numpy to 1.13.1 and then it promptly stopped working on me :S.  Will report back when I get this fixed.

Comment: Reproduced on Win7/32B, `python 3.5.2` and `numpy 1.11.1`

Comment: @DanielF Ok so I reduced the size of X, as you suggested, but the effect persists.  I've edited my question with the code and output.

Comment: Yeah, I got ~200% for `(1000,1000)` also, but jumped to ~110% for `(100,100)`  - Which is weird, that's awfully small to be a memory thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152009/discussion-between-jmracek-and-daniel-f).

Comment: Actually, I think you have to make the arrays much bigger, at least along the dimension that you are operating on, to consistently see the difference.

Comment: sorry, @jmracek, chat's blocked at work for me :)

Comment: @DanielF I think stack exchange forced me to do that because we are apparently getting too chatty?  Anyway, I'm reproducing your results when I drop to 100x100 matrices.  I'm going to try this on OSX tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot confirm your second result on OSX (various Python versions) - it is similar to your first result:

```
In [27]: X = np.ones((10000,10000),dtype='float64')
    ...: print(X.dtype)
    ...: print(X.flags)
    ...: 
    ...: %timeit np.sum(X,axis=0)
    ...: 
    ...: %timeit np.sum(X,axis=1)
    ...: 
float64
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
10 loops, best of 3: 67.6 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 62 ms per loop
```

EDIT: I repeated all your computations using directly `timeit.repeat()`:

```
import timeit
t = timeit.repeat('np.sum(X,axis=0)', setup="import numpy as np; X = np.ones((10000,10000),dtype='float64')", repeat=50, number=1); print(min(t));
t = timeit.repeat('np.sum(X,axis=1)', setup="import numpy as np; X = np.ones((10000,10000),dtype='float64')", repeat=50, number=1); print(min(t));
t = timeit.repeat('np.sum(X,axis=0)', setup="import numpy as np; X = np.ones((10000,10000),dtype='int64')", repeat=50, number=1); print(min(t));
t = timeit.repeat('np.sum(X,axis=1)', setup="import numpy as np; X = np.ones((10000,10000),dtype='int64')", repeat=50, number=1); print(min(t));
```

with these timings:

```
Python 2.7.13 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:05:08) 
IPython 5.3.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
numpy 1.12.1

0.0637669563293 # float64, axis=0
0.0558688640594 # float64, axis=1
0.0669782161713 # int64, axis=0
0.0576930046082 # int64, axis=1
```

and

```
Python 3.6.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul 20 2017, 13:14:59) 
IPython 6.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
numpy 1.13.1

0.06289491400821134
0.05558946297969669
0.0670205659698695
0.057950171001721174
```

and

```
Python 3.5.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Mar  6 2017, 12:15:08) 
IPython 5.3.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
numpy 1.11.3

0.06345970398979262
0.05561513203429058
0.07043616304872558
0.057934076990932226
```

Finally, on my Android phone:

```
Python 3.6.2 (default, Jul 19 2017, 11:01:41)
IPython 6.1.0
numpy 1.12.0

0.39130385394673795
0.24979593697935343
0.42852322908584028
0.28863119706511497
```

and Windows system (python 3.4 32bit):

```
0.158213707338
0.149441164907
0.365552662475
0.128456460354
```

Comment: Hmm... ok I'll have to run this code on another computer.  This is very strange, since I'm able to reproduce this result on my machine.

Comment: I reproduced it on my machine @jmracek.  Maybe a version or hardware difference.  What version of `numpy` and `python` are you running AGN ?

Comment: I'm running python 3.6 and numpy 1.11.3 on a Microsoft Surface Pro 3.

Comment: When I try this alternative method for timing I still get the same results as before.

Comment: @DanielF All tests are on OSX. I edited my answer to include version information.

Comment: @jmracek On one occasion, magic method `%timeit` added additional time compared to the direct `timeit` - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45610320/8033585

Comment: @AGNGazer Thank you for your help.  I'm going to try on OSX tomorrow morning.  At this point I am still totally clueless why this could be happening.